# One d3 line on nested data with mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested, mouseover, line-plot

I have managed to create the line and the plot that I want but unfortunately I have failed to create a simple hover over the line.

This is the main code:

```
var groupclusters = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.clustindex; })
            .entries(expsdata);

var svg = d3.select("#container3")
                .selectAll("svg")
                .data(groupclusters)
                .enter()
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

             svg.append("path")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", '#a65628')
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function(d){
                    return d3.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return x(d.mtbname); })
                  .y(function(d) { return y(+d.clustcenters); })(d.values);
                });
```

and the above code creates the plots below:

[image]

How will I make it when I hover over the line to get a value?

I tried this below but on the hover I get "undefined", which means it cannot find the data/values! But the data is there (groupclusters)!

```
             svg.append("path")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", '#a65628')
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function(d){
                    return d3.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return x(d.mtbname); })
                  .y(function(d) { return y(+d.clustcenters); })(d.values);
                }).on('mouseover', function(d){
                               tooltip1.transition().duration(10)
                                       .style("opacity",0.8)
                                       .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+20)+"px")
                                       .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-35)+"px");
                               tooltip1.html("<p>"+d.mtbname+"</p>");})
                  .on('mouseout', function(d){
                             tooltip1.transition().duration(100).style("opacity",0);});;
```

**EDIT**

I am using d3 5.7.0. These are my scales:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(mtbsnameslist)
                .range([ 0, width ]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(expsdata, function(d) { return +d.clustcenters; })])
                .range([ height, 0 ]);
```

Comment: There is no single datum bound to the line. Instead, the line data is an array of objects. Thus, you have to get the `y` position of the cursor, use the (inverted) scale to get the respective `mtbname` (I hope they are unique) and then displaying it's name.

Comment: The mtbnames are  unique yes. I used y.invert(d3.line().x(function(d) { return x(d.mtbname); })) but I get a NaN. I also try with var coordinates= d3.mouse(this);
var x = coordinates[0];var y = coordinates[1]; But I am not sure what to do after that.

Comment: You have to invert the mouse position. Share your scale and the D3 version.

Comment: Just added them in the EDIT section

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Gerardo Furtado I found the answer! Changed the mouseover to:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
                    x.invert = function(x) {
                                    var domain = this.domain();
                                    var range = this.range();
                                    var scale = d3.scaleQuantize().domain(range).range(domain);
                                    return scale(x);
                                    };
                    var coordinates= d3.mouse(this);
                    var xcoo = coordinates[0];
                    
                               tooltip1.transition().duration(10)
                                       .style("opacity",0.8)
                                       .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+20)+"px")
                                       .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-35)+"px");
                               tooltip1.html("<p>"+x.invert(xcoo)+"</p>");})
.on('mouseout', function(d){
         tooltip1.transition().duration(100).style("opacity",0);});
```